# Mojolicious on Redhat EC2 instance, can't install due to dependencies?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dependencies, mojolicious

I spun up a new EC2 instance with Redhat OS. I am trying to install Mojolicious with `cpanm Mojolicious` but it keeps telling me `Can't locate <package> in @INC`. The first few times I just did `cpanm <package>` and then `sudo reboot`. Then I try to install Mojolicious again but every time it's missing something new and there could be hundreds of these, right? So how do get it to install all the dependencies for Mojolicious?

As an aside, I built a mojolicious app on OSX and I am trying to host it in on EC2. The install was perfect on my Mac.

Comment: Two of the modules I was missing were `Digest::MD5` and `Compress::Raw::Zlib` which according to [this mojo documentation](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/perlmodlib#Standard-Modules) are supposed to be standard. Did perl install incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system perl provided by RedHat is intentionally crippled (possibly in violation of the Perl license!). The easy fix is to install the `perl-core` module (to install the core modules of Perl, sigh).

The recommended answer however is to not use the system perl interpreter, leave that to system usage. Instead try [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).